# Finding ubuntu user account running tor for tor-arm install

Tags: configuration, relays, nyx

I am wondering how I go about finding the user that is running tor when installed on ubuntu. The quote below says that tor should be running as a separate user. I have a relay setup and currently running. I am doing this so that I can setup tor-arm based upon the instructions given here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-relay-debian.html.en#after

"The best approach for most users is to run your relay on Debian or Ubuntu using the system Tor package — the deb takes care of running Tor as a separate user, making sure it has enough file descriptors available, starting it at boot, and so on."

I used option 2 on the following page to complete the ubuntu install:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

Comment: `ps aux | grep torrc` from the command line. Use `torrc` in your grep to weed out any other strings containing "tor". The user will be the first field in the output.

Comment: If you're wondering why a separate user is created when the package is installed, have a read of https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch9.en.html#s-bpp-lower-privs

Comment: Wish you would have made this an answer so I could select it, as what you said worked. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ps aux | grep torrc from the command line. Use torrc in your grep to weed out any other strings containing "tor". The user will be the first field in the output" - Richard Horrocks

This command worked but was submitted as a comment. I just wanted to place this into an answer so my question can be considered solved. All credit to Richard Horrocks for helping me solve this.